# Can you use network load balancing on an IIS cluster hosting a WCF application?

Tags: wcf, iis, cluster-computing, endpoint, nlb

Thanks for taking the time to read this. I'm new to using WCF and I'm in the early stages of creating a new web front end to our existing system. I want to use network load balancing on an IIS cluster where each node is hosting a WCF application which contains logic on where to route the request...

Is something like this possible?
Are the endpoints of the WCF application the same as the IIS end points? 
Any help/suggestions/advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not quite understand the reason for "WCF application which contains logic on where to route the request". NLB will route requests to some Cluster node for you. What do you want to achieve in your code?

Comment: For example, we have  one web service that handles all core web service requests, another that handles all trading requests etc. We have different WCFs running on the back end which handle these requests. The way I imagine it working is the NLB routes the request to a WCF application hosted by one of the IIS nodes in the cluster and that application determines based on parameters passed in the message which web service to direct the request to. Not sure if that will work though..

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the information needed to determine which service (or cluster of services) should be called is in the initial WCF message and the NLB would route the message.

Read [WCF Addressing In Depth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163412.aspx)

- *IIS Addressing Considerations* will answer your IIS endpoints
  question.
- *Logical vs. Physical Addressing* gives ideas on how to route
  with an intermediary (in this case NLB).